# Selenium - test doesn't click on menu item but if I click it, the test completes

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I started using Selenium WebDriver today and I'm writing a login/logout test.

```
[Test]
    public void TestLoginLogout()
    {
        //Define browser and target URL
        IWebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver();
        browser.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        browser.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://test-test.net");
        browser.Manage().Window.Maximize();

        //Define login credentials and webpage elements
        IWebElement fieldUsername = browser.FindElement(By.Id("mat-input-0"));
        IWebElement fieldPassword = browser.FindElement(By.Id("mat-input-1"));

        //Perform login using login credentials
        fieldUsername.SendKeys("tester");
        fieldPassword.SendKeys("tester123");
        IWebElement buttonLogin = browser.FindElement(By.Id("LoginButton"));
        buttonLogin.Click();

        //Perform logout action
        Actions action = new Actions(browser);
        IWebElement buttonLogout = browser.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[@class='menu']/div/ul[@class='list']/li[last()]/a"));
        action.MoveToElement(buttonLogout).Click();
        //Locate confirm button in modal window
        browser.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        IWebElement buttonConfirm = browser.FindElement(By.XPath(".//button[@class='swal-button swal-button--confirm']"));
        buttonConfirm.Click();
    }
```

When the test logs in, it should click on Logout button in the menu and then click on confirm button when the modal dialog pops up. The problem is,the test doesn't click on the Logout button, but if I manually click on the Logout button while the test halts, then the test completes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the value of buttonLogout when you debug this code ?

Comment: @auburg hello, I've posted a new reply - found a solution!

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: The problem was with the clicking of Logout button in the menu. Seems like the test runs too fast and since our application has a loader element between the login page and the homepage, the test tried to click on the logout button while the loader element was still present. This is what I did:

Since **ExpectedConditions** is deprecated in current WebDrivers version, I downloaded the following NuGet package: DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers

I declared a variable that defined how long the browser will have to wait for element to be present/clickable before throwing a time-out and a IJavaScript executor that handles the clicking:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)browser;
var wait = new WebDriverWait(browser, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));
```

And finally, I changed the way that logout button and confirm button (inside modal) are clicked:

```
//Perform logout action
        var buttonLogout = wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(".//div[@class='menu']/div/ul[@class='list']/li[last()]/a")));
        executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", buttonLogout);

        //Locate confirm button in modal window
        var buttonConfirm = wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(".//button[@class='swal-button swal-button--confirm']")));
        executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", buttonConfirm);
```

And now the test executes successfully!